# How do I create methods for a class?

Tags: r, methods, r-s3

In an assignment I've written the function below (learnvq) that calculates the proximity of some data points to other labelled data points and then assigns those labels to the first set based on the closest point. I return the output from this function as a list of the class "learnvq".

I now need to write a method for this class that will use a new matrix and predict the labels based on the out put from the function. I've written the function and it seems to work fine, but I have no idea how to add it as a method of the class "learnvq"?

```
n <- 100
X <- cbind(x1 = runif(n, -1.5, 1.5),
       x2 = runif(n, -1.5, 1.5)) # Generate random points
y <- as.integer(rowSums(X^2)<1) # Determine whether inside the circle#
idx <- sample(100, 10) # Mess up 10 class labels ...
y[idx] <- 1-y[idx] # ... by flipping the label
```

##############################################################################################

## part 1: defining the class learnvq

```
learnvq <- function(X,y,K=10, eta=.25, alpha=.5, H=25) {
is <- c(sample(which(y==0),K,replace=TRUE), sample(which(y==1),K,replace=TRUE))
X.prototype <- X[is,]
y.prototype <- y[is]

#Function closest to find the position of my matrix which contains the closest point to a vector
closest <- function(mat,vec) { # function to calculate the closest value
dist <-  0* mat[,1] # creates the empty vector same length as number of rows

for (i in 1:nrow(mat))  # loops through the matrix
{dist[i] <- sum((mat[i,] - vec)^2)} # subtracts the vector from the row and takes the absolute value. 
Assigns the value to dist[i]

min.coord <- which.min(dist) # takes the smallest value- equates to the closest distance
return(min.coord)          # returns the position of the smallest value

}
Covariate.matrix <- X[is,] # copies covariates matrix X for use in the loops below- dont want to 
update the original above- need that too.
###put the loops here ###
for (h in 1:H){
for (i in 1:n){ 
  # finding prototype x.star in k closest to xi
  k <- closest(X.prototype,X[i,])
  #updating the X.prototype and Y.prototype with the information from k:
  if (y[i] == y.prototype[k])
    {
    X.prototype[k,] <- X.prototype[k,] + eta*(X[i,]-X.prototype[k,])
    }
  
  else   {
    X.prototype[k,] <- X.prototype[k,] - eta*(X[i,]-X.prototype[k,])
  }
  }
  }

  object <- list(Covariate.matrix=Covariate.matrix, y.prototypes= y.prototype, X.prototypes.star= 
  X.prototype,y.prototypes.star = y.prototype)
  class(object) <- "learnvq"
  object
  }

  check <- learnvq(X,y)
```

#######################################################################################################

## part 2: Predict method

```
  predict.learnvq <- function(object, New.Mat) {

  #Function closest to find the position of my matrix which contains the closest point to a vector
  closest <- function(mat,vec) { # function to calculate the closest value
  dist <-  0* mat[,1] # creates the empty vector same length as number of rows

  for (i in 1:nrow(mat))  # loops through the matrix
  {dist[i] <- sum((mat[i,] - vec)^2)} # subtracts the vector from the row. Assigns the value to 
  dist[i]

  min.coord <- which.min(dist) # takes the smallest value- equates to the closest distance
  return(min.coord)          # returns the position of the smallest value

  }

  #extracts the rows from X.new and compares them to the X.prototypes and then calculates the 
  corresponding y label
  if (missing(New.Mat)) # if statement to allow for missing X.new argument
  {New.Mat = object$Covariate.matrix} # if New.Mat is omitted it uses the covariates of the training 
  data- 

  y.proto.test<- 0*nrow(New.Mat)
  for (j in 1:nrow(New.Mat))# loops through the matrix
  {y.proto.test[j] <- closest(check$X.prototypes.star, New.Mat[j,])} # returns the y.prototype 
  position that the new rows are closest to.
  estimated.class.labels <- check$y.prototypes.star[y.proto.test] # contains the row #s of the points 
  closest to the X.new points.
  return(estimated.class.labels)

  }

  X.new <- cbind(x1=runif(10, -1.5, 1.5),  #creates a vector of unclassified points
           x2=runif(10, -1.5, 1.5))
  fitted.y <- predict.learnvq(check$X.prototypes.star, X.new)
```

Comment: Please *format your code properly*, especially using consistent indentation. At the moment it’s almost unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

> I have no idea how to add it as a method of the class "learnvq"?

You’ve already done it. By naming your method `predict.learnqv`, you’ve created a `predict` method for your `learnqv` class. You can now call it:

```
result = predict(learnqv_object, other_arguments…)
```

… and this will automatically call `predict.learnqv`.

If you write this code in a package, you also need to take care of properly exporting the S3 method name, but for “simple” R code the above is sufficient. Do read read [the chapter on S3](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/s3.html) in *Advanced R*, it contains more relevant information.